# Apache Jackrabbit JCA 2.7.5 .docx and .xlsx indexing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jcr, jackrabbit, jcr-sql2

I'm ussing the Appache Jackrabbit JCA 2.7.5, the problem is that files .docx and .xlsx is not indexed.

My steps :

- Deploy the [Jackrabbit JCA](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jackrabbit/2.7.5/jackrabbit-jca-2.7.5.rar) as `resource adapter` on glassfish
- create a `Connector Connection Pool` for the `resource adapter` indicating the `ConfigFile=path/to/the/repository.xml` and `HomeDir=path/to/the //miss the repository.xml`
- create a `Connector Resources` for the connector pool (the jndi)
- create web application
- create class to get session from the connector ressources (code below)

  ```
  import java.io.Serializable;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import javax.annotation.Resource;
  import javax.ejb.Stateless;
  import javax.jcr.LoginException;
  import javax.jcr.Repository;
  import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
  import javax.jcr.Session;
  import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials;
  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.naming.NamingException;
  @Stateless
  public class OcmRepository implements Serializable {

      public Repository repository;
      public Session session;

      public OcmRepository() {
      }

      public Session getSession(String log, String mdp) throws LoginException, RepositoryException, NamingException, MalformedURLException {
          InitialContext initalContext = new InitialContext();
          repository = (Repository) initalContext.lookup("jndi/jca");
          session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials(log, mdp.toCharArray()), null);
          return session;
      }
  }
  ```
- Create custom filetype

  ```
  import javax.jcr.PropertyType;
  import javax.jcr.Session;
  import javax.jcr.nodetype.NodeType;
  import javax.jcr.nodetype.NodeTypeManager;
  import javax.jcr.nodetype.NodeTypeTemplate;
  import javax.jcr.nodetype.PropertyDefinitionTemplate;

  /**
   *
   * @author nathan
   */
  public class FileType {
      public static void RegisterFileType(Session session) throws Exception {        
          NodeTypeManager nodeTypeManager = session.getWorkspace().getNodeTypeManager();

          NodeTypeTemplate nodeType = nodeTypeManager.createNodeTypeTemplate();
          nodeType.setName("FileType");
          String[] str = {"nt:resource"};        
          nodeType.setDeclaredSuperTypeNames(str);
          nodeType.setMixin(false);
          nodeType.setQueryable(true);


          PropertyDefinitionTemplate path = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
          path.setName("jcr:path");
          path.setRequiredType(PropertyType.PATH);
          path.setQueryOrderable(false);
          path.setFullTextSearchable(false);
          nodeType.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(path);

          PropertyDefinitionTemplate nom = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
          nom.setName("jcr:nom");
          nom.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);
          nom.setQueryOrderable(true);
          nom.setFullTextSearchable(true);
          nodeType.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(nom);

          PropertyDefinitionTemplate description = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
          description.setName("jcr:description");
          description.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);
          description.setQueryOrderable(true);
          description.setFullTextSearchable(true);
          nodeType.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(description);

          PropertyDefinitionTemplate motsCles = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
          motsCles.setName("jcr:motsCles");
          motsCles.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);
          motsCles.setQueryOrderable(true);
          motsCles.setFullTextSearchable(true);
          nodeType.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(motsCles);

          PropertyDefinitionTemplate size = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
          size.setName("jcr:size");
          size.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);
          size.setQueryOrderable(true);
          size.setFullTextSearchable(false);
          nodeType.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(size);

          PropertyDefinitionTemplate users = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
          users.setName("jcr:users");
          users.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);
          users.setQueryOrderable(true);
          users.setFullTextSearchable(false);
          nodeType.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(users);

          PropertyDefinitionTemplate groupe = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
          groupe.setName("jcr:groupe");
          groupe.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);
          groupe.setQueryOrderable(true);
          groupe.setFullTextSearchable(false);
          nodeType.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(groupe);

          NodeType newnodetype = nodeTypeManager.registerNodeType(nodeType, true);             
          session.save();        
      }

  }
  ```
- Create the abstract class for persistence

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;

  import javax.jcr.Session;

  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.Filter;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.impl.FilterImpl;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.impl.QueryImpl;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.Query;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.QueryManager;

  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.manager.ObjectContentManager;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.manager.impl.ObjectContentManagerImpl;

  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.mapper.Mapper;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.mapper.impl.annotation.AnnotationMapperImpl;

  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.reflection.ReflectionUtils;


  /**
   *
   * @author nathan
   */
  public abstract class AbstractBean<T> {

      private Class<T> entityClass;
      private ObjectContentManager ocm;
      private Mapper mapper;

      public AbstractBean(Class<T> entityClass){
          this.entityClass = entityClass;
      }

      /**
       * Construct the Bean according to the extended class
       * This will be also construct the ObjectContentManager nammed ocm with the default Mapper
       * @param session javax.jcr.Session attached to the Bean
       * @return The mapping class found for the desired java bean class
       */
      public AbstractBean(Class<T> entityClass,Session session){
          this.entityClass = entityClass;
          ocm = new ObjectContentManagerImpl(session, this.getDefaultMapper());
      }

      /**
       * @return ObjectContentManager of the Bean
       */
      public ObjectContentManager getOcm() throws Exception{
          return ocm;
      }

      /**
       * Construct the Bean according to the extended class
       * This will be also construct the ObjectContentManager nammed ocm with the param Mapper given
       * @param session from "javax.jcr.Session" attached to the Bean
       * @param map from "org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.mapper.Mapper" which 
       * is the use to map entity between apllication and The repository
       * @return ObjectContentManager of the Bean
       */   
      public ObjectContentManager getOcm(Session session, Mapper map) throws Exception{
          return new ObjectContentManagerImpl(session, map);
      }

      public void setOcm(ObjectContentManager ocm) {
          this.ocm = ocm;
      }

      private Mapper getDefaultMapper(){
          ReflectionUtils.setClassLoader(com.ged.ocm.entity.Groupe.class.getClassLoader());
          List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
          classes.add(com.ged.ocm.entity.Fichier.class);
          classes.add(com.ged.ocm.entity.Dossier.class);
          classes.add(com.ged.ocm.entity.Groupe.class);
          classes.add(com.ged.ocm.entity.SimpleNode.class);
          return new AnnotationMapperImpl(classes);
      }

      public Mapper getMapper() {
          return mapper;
      }

      public void setMapper(Mapper mapper) {
          this.mapper = mapper;
      }

      public void setLoader(Class classe){        
          ReflectionUtils.setClassLoader(classe.getClassLoader());
      }

      public void create(T entity) {
          ocm.insert(entity);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public void edit(T entity) {
          ocm.update(entity);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public void remove(T entity) {
          ocm.remove(entity);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public void refresh(){
          ocm.refresh(true);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public void copy(String orgPath, String destPath){
          ocm.copy(orgPath, destPath);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public void move(String orgPath, String destPath){
          ocm.move(orgPath, destPath);
          ocm.save();
      }
      public void removeByPath(String path) {
          ocm.remove(path);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public void removeAllByEqual(Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addEqualTo(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          ocm.remove(query);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public void removeAllByEqual(String nodePath,Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope(nodePath);
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addEqualTo(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          ocm.remove(query);
          ocm.save();
      }

      public boolean isPathExist(String path){
          return ocm.objectExists(path);
      }

      public T findByPath(String path) {
          try {            
              return (T)ocm.getObject(path);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              return null;
          }
      }

      public T findOneByEqual(Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addEqualTo(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);

          T result = null;
          try {            
              result = results.get(0);
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }

          return result;
      }

      public List<T> findAllByEqual(Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope("//");
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addEqualTo(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results;
      }


      public List<T> findAllByLike(Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope("//");
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addLike(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results;
      }

      public List<T> findAllByLikeScoped(String scope,Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope(scope);
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addLike(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results;
      }

      public List<T> findAllByOrLike(String attr,String[] val){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope("//");
          filter.addOrFilter(attr, val);

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results;
      }

      public T findOneByEqual(String nodePath, Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope(nodePath);
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addEqualTo(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          T result = results.get(0);
          return result;
      }

      public List<T> findAllByEqual(String nodePath, Map<String,String> filters){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope(nodePath);
          for (String key : filters.keySet())filter.addEqualTo(key, filters.get(key));

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results;
      }

      public List<T> findAllByString(String query){        
          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query,javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);
          return results;
      } 


      public List<T> findAllByParentPath(String nodePath){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope(nodePath);

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);
          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results;

      }
      public List<T> findAllByParentPathOrder(String nodePath, String ordering){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope(nodePath);

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);
  //        query.addOrderByDescending(ordering);
          query.addOrderByAscending(ordering);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results;

      }

      public int coutChild(String nodePath){
          QueryManager queryManager = ocm.getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(entityClass);
          filter.setScope(nodePath);

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<T> results = (List<T>) ocm.getObjects(query);
          return results.size();
      }

      public boolean ifExistByPath(String path){
          return ocm.objectExists(path);
      }

      public String getParentPath(String path){
          String parent="";
          String[] tmp=path.split("/");
          for (int i = 1; i < (tmp.length-1); i++) {
              parent+="/"+tmp[i];
          }
          return parent;                
      }
  }
  ```
- Create the bean

  ```
  import javax.ejb.Stateless;
  import com.ged.ocm.entity.Fichier;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;
  import javax.jcr.Node;
  import javax.jcr.NodeIterator;
  import javax.jcr.Session;
  import javax.jcr.Workspace;
  import javax.jcr.query.QueryResult;
  import javax.jcr.query.qom.FullTextSearch;
  import javax.jcr.query.qom.StaticOperand;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.Filter;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.Query;
  import org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.query.QueryManager;

  @Stateless
  public class FichierBean extends AbstractBean<Fichier>{    
      public FichierBean() {
          super(Fichier.class);
      }
      public FichierBean(Session session) {
          super(Fichier.class,session);
      }

      public List<Fichier> findAllByContains(String motCles) throws Exception {
          String requette = "SELECT * FROM FileType AS Res WHERE CONTAINS (Res.*, '*"+motCles+"*')";
          List<Fichier> results = (List<Fichier>) this.getOcm().getObjects(requette, javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);
          return results;                
      }
      public List<Fichier> findAllByContains(String path,String motCles) throws Exception {
          String requette = "SELECT * FROM FileType AS Res WHERE CONTAINS (Res.*, '*"+motCles+"*') ORDER BY Res.nom";
          List<Fichier> tmp = (List<Fichier>) this.getOcm().getObjects(requette, javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);

          List<Fichier> results = new ArrayList<Fichier>();
          for (Fichier fichier : tmp) {
              if(fichier.getPath().startsWith(path))results.add(fichier);
          }
          return results;                
      }


      public List<Fichier> fulltextByOCM(String motCles) throws Exception {
          QueryManager queryManager = this.getOcm().getQueryManager();

          Filter filter;
          filter = queryManager.createFilter(com.ged.ocm.entity.Fichier.class);
          filter.addContains(".", "*"+motCles+"*");

          Query query = queryManager.createQuery(filter);

          List<Fichier> results = (List<Fichier>) this.getOcm().getObjects(query);
          return results;
      }

  }
  ```

My configuration files :

- repository.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 1.6//EN"
                          "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-1.6.dtd">
  <Repository>        
  <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository"/>
  </FileSystem>
  -->

  <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
      <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://:3306/db_ged_mysql" />
      <param name="user" value="root" />
      <param name="password" value="root" />
      <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_R_FS_"/>
  </FileSystem>

  <!--
      security configuration
  -->
  <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
      <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleAccessManager" />
      <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleLoginModule">
          <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous" />
      </LoginModule>
  </Security>

  <!--
      location of workspaces root directory and name of default workspace
  -->
  <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>
  <!--
      workspace configuration template:
      used to create the initial workspace if there's no workspace yet
  -->
  <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">

      <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.db.SimpleDbPersistenceManager">
          <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://:3306/db_ged_mysql" />
          <param name="user" value="root" />
          <param name="password" value="root" />
          <param name="schema" value="mysql" />
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_PM_${wsp.name}_" />
          <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
      </PersistenceManager>
      <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
          <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://:3306/db_ged_mysql" />
          <param name="user" value="root" />
          <param name="password" value="root" />
          <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_FS_${wsp.name}_"/>
      </FileSystem>

      <!--
          Search index and the file system it uses.
          class: FQN of class implementing the QueryHandler interface
      -->
      <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
          <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/workspaces/${wsp.name}/index"/>
          <param name="tikaConfigPath" value="${rep.home}/tika-config.xml"/>
          <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true"/>
          <param name="minMergeDocs" value="100"/>
          <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="3"/>
          <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="2147483647"/>
          <param name="mergeFactor" value="10"/>
          <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000"/>
          <param name="bufferSize" value="10"/>
          <param name="cacheSize" value="1000"/>
          <param name="forceConsistencyCheck" value="false"/>
          <param name="enableConsistencyCheck" value="false"/>
          <param name="autoRepair" value="true"/>
          <param name="analyzer" value="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
          <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl"/>
          <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="true"/>
          <param name="resultFetchSize" value="2147483647"/>
          <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="0"/>
          <param name="extractorTimeout" value="100"/>
          <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100"/>
          <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
          <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DefaultXMLExcerpt"/>
      </SearchIndex>
  </Workspace>

  <!--
      Configures the versioning
  -->
  <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
      <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
          <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://:3306/db_ged_mysql" />
          <param name="user" value="root" />
          <param name="password" value="root" />
          <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_V_FS_"/>
      </FileSystem>
      <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.db.SimpleDbPersistenceManager">
          <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://:3306/db_ged_mysql" />
          <param name="user" value="root" />
          <param name="password" value="root" />
          <param name="schema" value="mysql" />
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="J_V_PM_" />
          <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
      </PersistenceManager>
  </Versioning>

  <!--
      Search index for content that is shared repository wide
      (/jcr:system tree, contains mainly versions)

  <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
      <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
      <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="2"/>
      <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
  </SearchIndex>
  -->

  <!--
      Cluster configuration with system variables.

  -->

  <RepositoryLockMechanism class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.CooperativeFileLock" />

  </Repository>
  ```
- tika-config.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <properties>

  <mimeTypeRepository resource="/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml" magic="false"/>

  <parsers>

  <parser name="parse-dcxml" class="org.apache.tika.parser.xml.DcXMLParser">
    <mime>application/xml</mime>
    <mime>image/svg+xml</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-office" class="org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser">
    <mime>application/x-tika-msoffice</mime>
    <mime>application/msword</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-powerpoint</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.visio</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-outlook</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-ooxml" class="org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser">
    <mime>application/x-tika-ooxml</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-html" class="org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser">
    <mime>text/html</mime>
    <mime>application/xhtml+xml</mime>
    <mime>application/x-asp</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser mame="parse-rtf" class="org.apache.tika.parser.rtf.RTFParser">
    <mime>application/rtf</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-pdf" class="org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser">
    <mime>application/pdf</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-txt" class="org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser">
    <mime>text/plain</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-openoffice" class="org.apache.tika.parser.opendocument.OpenOfficeParser">
    <mime>application/vnd.sun.xml.writer</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template</mime>
    <mime>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.image</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template</mime>
    <mime>application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-image" class="org.apache.tika.parser.image.ImageParser">
    <mime>image/bmp</mime>
    <mime>image/gif</mime>
    <mime>image/jpeg</mime>
    <mime>image/png</mime>
    <mime>image/tiff</mime>
    <mime>image/vnd.wap.wbmp</mime>
    <mime>image/x-icon</mime>
    <mime>image/x-psd</mime>
    <mime>image/x-xcf</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-class" class="org.apache.tika.parser.asm.ClassParser">
    <mime>application/x-tika-java-class</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-mp3" class="org.apache.tika.parser.mp3.Mp3Parser">
    <mime>audio/mpeg</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-midi" class="org.apache.tika.parser.audio.MidiParser">
    <mime>application/x-midi</mime>
    <mime>audio/midi</mime>
  </parser>

  <parser name="parse-audio" class="org.apache.tika.parser.audio.AudioParser">
    <mime>audio/basic</mime>
    <mime>audio/x-wav</mime>
    <mime>audio/x-aiff</mime>
  </parser>

  </parsers>

  </properties>
  ```

All query from the bean work except when I call the function `public List<Fichier> findAllByContains(String path,String motCles)` to fulltext search into .docx and .xslx document. Fulltext search on .pdf, .txt, .xml, .xls, .doc, ... work perfectly.

Comment: Does anyone found solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is focused on JARs of the [jackrabbit-jca-2.7.5.rar](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jackrabbit/2.7.5/jackrabbit-jca-2.7.5.rar)!

There are errors on dependency so I make these change :

- add apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
- add apache-mime4j-core-0.7.jar
- add commons-compress-1.5.jar

Add these JARs in the jackrabbit-jca-2.7.5.rar before deploying this!

And the indexation of .docx, .xlsx, ... wors succesfully!

Thank you for @Ashok Felix

Answer (score 2):

Ref: http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/Office-2007-documents-not-being-indexed-in-Jackrabbit-2-4-3-td4657380.html

> On the same line, I have observed commons-compress-1.5.jar is required
>   by Tika parser in case of OOXML types of documents (i.e. office 2007
>   documents).
>
> Now, I am able to index & search most of types of documents (office
>   2007 - docx, pptx, xlsx , office 2003 - doc, ppt, xls, PDF) using
>   below 2 steps:
>
> (1) Updated repository.xml & added 
>         
>        Further details can be found at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-3287
>
> (2) Added
>   commons-compress-1.5.jar classpath while running
>   jackrabbit-standalone-2.6.2.jar