# How to set the name of the repository JackRabbit 2.0?

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I'm looking to set the name of the repository, where I will write on my disk using JackRabbit. I didn't find it in the doc. I can't use JackRabbit Oak because of compatibility.

Comment: So you use Jackrabbit JCA or standalone or RMI?!

Comment: I use it in a java project. I added the dependencies in my pom.xml

Comment: A java web project or java application Project!
you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084099/apache-jackrabbit-jca-2-7-5-docx-and-xlsx-indexing

Comment: Sorry, it's a java application, no web in this project :/

Comment: Nice try to make it better looking, but honestly, this question should have been deleted on spot