# Jackrabbit: What is the difference between PersistenceManager, DataStore & FileSystem and how to use them effectively?

Tags: java, jackrabbit

**Understanding so far:**

*PersistenceManager*: Persistence Manager is a critical part of Jackrabbit that stores the nodes and properties.

*DataStore*: Data Store is used in conjunction with PersistenceManager to store large content.

*FileSystem*: FileSystem is a low-level abstraction, which is used by Persistence Manager (and a few other components such as Versioning)

**Sources:**

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jackrabbit-configuration.html
http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/frequently-asked-questions.html
http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ
http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore

**Questions:**

- Is the above understanding correct?
- In production, the recommendation is to use database (such as MySQL) for jackrabbit metadata & small files along with bulk-store, resilient filesystem (such as S3) for large files. Configuration to be used for this:

  `<PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.MySqlPersistenceManager">` ...

  `<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.aws.ext.ds.S3DataStore">` ... (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-aws-ext)

  - Is this configuration right?
  - What should be the configuration for FileySystem?
- Should the above configuration be in `repository.xml` or `workspace.xml`?

Comment: You asked too many questions in one.
Better to see this link. 
https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ#Bundle_Database_PM

Answer (score 1):

The understanding is correct! But i add some :

- FileSystem is used to store configuration and other meta like : nodetype configuration, your namesapaces, versionnings
- PersistenceManager store your nodes and properties
- Datastore for storing large binary data

Your configuration must be in a repository.xml. In this file you can configure all of your workspace, so workspace.xml is generated from your repository.xml , no need to write a workspace.xml

For an example of a repository.xml , see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084099/apache-jackrabbit-jca-2-7-5-docx-and-xlsx-indexing).

Comment: When workspaces already exist and configuration in repository.xml is changed, it does not affect the existing workspaces. The `<workspace>` section in repository.xml is only used a template for new workspaces. Also, if each workspace needs different configurations, we need to change workspace.xml